# Issue with Telerik Grid Horizontal Scroll bar

Tags: telerik-grid

i am seeing some issues with telerik grid view

here is the scenario

i have implemented a telerik grid controller in one of my project which has a feature of filters, now once all records are displayed, i am scrolling to the end of grid and applying filter criteria and now after applying filter there are no records matching my filter criteria so its showing **"No records to display."**, now i am **unable to see the horizontal scroll bar** where i can scroll and remove filter to display all records.

is there any way i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Write the below script onDataBinding() event

```
$("tr.t-no-data td").html("No records to display.");

$("tr.t-no-data td").attr("style", "width:" + $(".t-grid-header").find("table").css("width") + "!important");
```

or

var colspan = $(".t-grid-header-wrap").find("th").length;
        var emptyRow = "No Records Found.";
        $(".t-grid-content").find("tbody").html(emptyRow);

Answer (score 0):

Change `t-grid-header` `padding-left` style:

```
   .t-rtl .t-grid.t-grid-rightscroll div.t-grid-header {
        padding-left: 17px !important;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
```